# jQuery inArray not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my validation the required fields can change.  I have an array (*required*) of input ids which are required.  If the array contains the string 'All' then all inputs are  required.

I'm trying to use JQuery.inArray() to determine if required.

```
function getIfRequired(id){
    console.log("id: "+id);
    console.log(required);
    console.log("inarray: "+jQuery.inArray(required, 'All'));

    if (jQuery.inArray(required, 'All') > -1){ return true; }
    else if(jQuery.inArray(required, id) != -1){ return true; }
    else{ return false; }
}
```

But it keeps returning '-1' (not found).

here are example log outputs:

```
id: clientname
["clientname", "sourceid", "clientcountry","clienttown", "clienttownid", "typeoflaw"] 
inarray: -1 

id: clientname
["All"] 
inarray: -1
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Why do you send in `'All'` instead of `id`? Also, the first argument should be the value and the second the array.

Comment: If you care to read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) you will notice that the method signature is `inArray(value, array)`. ;)

Comment: *facepalm* - one day people will check function documentation before making up their own syntax and getting confused..

Comment: facepalm indeed!!! Tbf I got the jquery.inarray line from existing code, never used it before.  Teach me for assuming it was correct

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I highly doubt that this becomes a trend. :)

Comment: @James In your defense, it's not consistent with jQuery's other methods, like `.map(array, ...)` or `.each(array, ...)`. It would be natural to assume that `inArray()` works the same way.

Comment: @James Fair enough, still would have thought you could have googled the syntax before making a post on SO though... anyway, not just you - the reason I commented is sooo many people are posting questions with simple answers like this and it gets frustrating

Comment: @SmokeyPHP, thats fair enough.  I did google, guess it was a case of the answer under my nose and not seeing it.  Cheers though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have your value and array parameters transposed, e.g.:

```
jQuery.inArray('All', required);
```

Answer (score 1):

You call wrong `jQuery.inArray`. First goes the value and then the array

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

write

```
jQuery.inArray('All', required);
```

instead of

```
jQuery.inArray(required, 'All');
```

Answer (score 0):

because `required` not found in `All`

You will write as below

```
 console.log("inarray: "+jQuery.inArray('All', required));
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)